# laravel mutliple row save to database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am a laravel beginner. Currently i am learning to do an inventory system. I have two table: goodsreceiveheader and goodsreceivedetail.

What can i do to allow multiple row save into database when submit button are clicked. Hope somebody will help me out as i had stuck in this for a few weeks=(

For goodsreceiveheader table, i have the field of:

```
id,
referencenumber,
vendorid(FK),
date,
createdby.
```

While goodsreceivedetail table, i have the field of:

```
id,
goodsreceiveheader_id(FK),
itemid(FK),
quantity,
costprice.
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.layout')

@section('content')
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create New Goods Receive</legend>
        @include('layouts.error')
        {!! Form::open(['url' => 'goodsreceive/save', 'method'=>'post']) !!}
        @include('goodsreceiveheader.partial._goodsreceiveheader_form')
        {!! Form::close() !!}


    </fieldset>
@endsection
```

My view:

```
<style>
    div#gr{
        padding: 20px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Goods Receive</h2>

    <hr>

        <div id="gr" class="row" style="background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <input name="createdby" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
                {!! Form::label('referencenumber', 'Reference Number:')!!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="referencenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference Number">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    {!! Form::label('date', 'Receive Date:')!!}
                    {!! Form::date('date',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::label('vendorid', 'Vendor ID:')!!}
                <select name="vendorid" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Vendor..</option>
                    @foreach($vendors as $vendor)
                        <option value="{{$vendor->id}}">{{$vendor->vendorid}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <th>Item Barcode</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cost Price</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;background: #eee">
            <a href="#" onclick="addRow()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </a>
        </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="itemid">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Barcode</option>
                    @foreach($items as $item)
                        <option value="{{$item->itemid}}">{{$item->itembarcode}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="costprice" class="form-control costprice"></td>
            <td  style="text-align: center"  onclick="cannotdelete()">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow()
    {
        var tr='<tr>'+
                '<td>'+
                '<select class="form-control" name="itemid">'+
                '<option value="" selected disabled>Select Barcode</option>'+
                '@foreach($items as $item)'+
                '<option value="{{$item->itemid}}">{{$item->itembarcode}}</option>'+
                '@endforeach'+
                '</select>'+
                '</td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="costprice" class="form-control costprice"></td>'+
                '<td class="remove" style="text-align: center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteRow()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>'+
                '</tr>';

        $('tbody').append(tr);
    }

    function deleteRow()
    {
        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function()
        {
            $(this).parent('tr').remove();
        });
    }

    function cannotdelete()
    {
        alert('You cannot delete the first row!!!')
    }

</script>
```

**My controller:**

```
 public function save(GoodsreceiveheaderRequest $request)
    { $data = array(
            'referencenumber'=>$request->referencenumber,
            'vendorid'=>$request->vendorid,
            'date'=>$request->date,
            'createdby'=>$request->createdby,
        );
        $i = DB::table('goodsreceiveheader')->insertGetId($data);

        $goodsreceivedetail = array(
            'goodsreceiveheader_id'=>$i,
            'itemid'=>$request->itemid,
            'quantity'=>$request->quantity,
            'costprice'=>$request->costprice,
        );

        $s = DB::table('goodsreceivedetail')->insert($goodsreceivedetail);

        Session::flash('message','You have successfully create goods receive.');

        return redirect('goodsreceive/goodsreceiveheader_list');
    }
```

Comment: too much code posted .. try reading the documentation, also in your js `addRow` you have blade directives mixed in js it will not work. Try working with arrays to pass multiple products to controller and then arrays again to save multiple rows. You need to read some tutorials.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. my js addRow are working as i can add a row for user to insert their item. user can click save and save the data to the database. just that its only save one row of data to db instead the others. So, what can i do for it? is there any tutorial that u can recommend for me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
public function save(GoodsreceiveheaderRequest $request)
        {
            $head = Goodsreceiveheader::findorNew($request->id);
            $head->referencenumber=$request->referencenumber;
            $head->vendorid=$request->vendorid;
            $head->date=$request->date;
            $head->createdby=$request->createdby;
            if ($head->save()){
                $id = $head->id;
                foreach($request->itemid as $key =>$item_id){
                    $data = array(
                                    'goodsreceiveheader_id'=>$id,
                                    'itemid'=>$request->itemid [$key],
                                    'quantity'=>$request->quantity [$key],
                                    'costprice'=>$request->costprice [$key],
                        );
                    Goodsreceivedetail::insert($data);
                }
            }
            Session::flash('message','You have successfully create goods receive.');

            return redirect('goodsreceive/goodsreceiveheader_list');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use insert function and pass your data as multiple array like
if model name is 'User' then below code will work for multiple entry

User::insert(['name'=>'xyz'],['name'=>'abc']);